# bug on vaadin version

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I use the vaadin version 7.7.9 but as indicated in the forum:

> https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/16814459/vaadin-combobox-menu-opens-wrong-place-on-google-chrome-www-browser

It has a bug, on combobox, I've decided to upgrade the version to 7.7.12 that has resolved the issue, but there is another bug; So I have decided to pass to version 7.7.24, unfortunately there is a bug like the one in version 7.7.9;
So I'm asking is that possible? In 7.7.9 have a bug resolved in 7.7.12 and introduced again in 7.7.23? Or there is some thing wrong, I do?

Comment: At least the regression tests that were introduced in 7.7.12 are still running without issues in 7.7.30, and with a quick glance I didn't spot any open issues or any mention of fixing such problems in the release notes between versions 7.7.24 and 7.7.30 notes either. If it's possible I'd try upgrading to 7.7.30 to confirm that, and if the problem still persists, create a new issue in https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/new , preferably with a simple test project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: thanks for your replay, indeed I ve tried with 7.7.30 but there was an issue with a method that wasn't found; the error was something like no such method.... may be I can try again with 7.7.30, could you please tell me if API has changed from 7.7.9 to 7.7.30?

Comment: I haven't been involved in all of those releases, but we've certainly tried to avoid removing any public API in maintenance releases. At the very most the changes should be on the level of changing a primarily internal method's return value from void to some actual value, and as such fairly trivial to fix if needed. Of course if you are using any add-ons, those might need updating too, and might have followed different updating logic. If you are using Eclipse, make sure you've run both `Maven -> Update Project...` and `mvn install` after the changes, and refreshed the project in Eclipse.

Comment: If I use 7.7.30 I get:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/jsoup/nodes/DataNode.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at com.vaadin.server.BootstrapHandler.setupMainDiv(BootstrapHandler.java:577)
        at com.vaadin.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:281)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.PortletBootstrapHandler.handleRequest(PortletBootstrapHandler.java:48)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1467)

Comment: Which version of jsoup do you have in your dependency tree? Should be 1.14.3, does something override that perhaps?

Comment: Yes it was missing :)

Comment: That might indeed cause some issues :) Assuming that the 7.7.30 works now, how is the ComboBox? Can you still reproduce the popup placement problem?

Comment: no with 7.7.30 at least for now seems ok :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!